# Получение (сохранение) HTML-страницы с хитрыми динамическими JavaScript элементами

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

**Добрый день**, уважаемые эксперты! Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться!
Есть сайт `avnet.com` и есть в нем таблицы, которые очень хитро формируются javascript-ом, например, на этой странице: https://www.avnet.com/shop/emea/c/antennas/antenna-modules/

Так вот, если я сохраняю страницу в браузере, то в тех местах, где должны быть наименования товара и ссылка на его страницу с детализацией стоят шаблоны для подстановки, например, `<a rel="nofollow" href="{{productDisplayURL}}" >{{mfPartNumber_ntk}}</a>`.

Пробовал с помощью модуля `requests` получать и сохранять эту страницу (сессии и заголовки использовал), с помощью selenium-а с webdriver-ом и все равно итог такой же. Самое интересное, что если посмотреть страницу через WebTools браузера, то весь сформированный DOM доступен, но не представляю, как можно сохранить именно этот результат. Пробовал исследовать посылаемые запросы на вкладке Network и вроде бы вижу, что отдается какой-то json, но так мне его получить с помощью `requests` не удалось.

Comment: Попробуйте https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer.

Comment: К сожалению, абсолютно все тоже самое... Но я продолжал экспериментировать и все-таки почти добился нужного эффекта с Selenium-ом - в качестве браузера использовал Chrome, но на этот раз добавил ему возможность подгружать мой текущий профиль, т.к. по умолчанию запускается с временным пустым профилем. И о чудо! - начал переходить по ссылкам, начал адекватно рендерить JS и `driver.page_source`... НО! Почему-то в конце работы программы браузер постоянно падает, хотя должен просто висеть окном и ждать физического действия! Абсолютно не могу понять причины! Может, сталкивался кто-нибудь с таким?..